How to design and run automated test for virtual machine interoperability in github action?
I know there are numerous test libraries and automated github action test examples for tcp/udp scenarios. But for other socket types(i.e. VSOCK, Hyper-V Socket), I have no idea to design proper automated tests for virtual machine interoperability. Is it possible to do that?
For example, there is a VSOCK server and I want write some automated tests for the VSOCK server.
